# Clear FileSystemCache in Symfony 3.4

Tags: symfony, caching

I use Symfony\Component\Cache\Simple\FilesystemCache;

It works when I $cache->set $cache->get $cache->clear() etc
I don't want to use a custom ttl. I want to clear the cache setted only with console.

But when I do php bin/console cache:clear, it doesn't clear cache I have set before with FilesystemCache.

I have tried to clear every pools with console but it doesn't clear $cache either.

Comment: Which error you found by run command ? Please add that in question

Comment: Thks, I finally figured out by myself (answer below)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It finally works, using AdapterInterface

```
<?php
namespace Gh\GhBundle\Manager;

use Symfony\Component\Cache\Adapter\AdapterInterface;

class AppManager
{


    protected $_rootDir;
    protected $_cache;

    public function __construct($rootDir, AdapterInterface $cache)
    {
       $this->_rootDir = $rootDir;
       $this->_cache = $cache;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * Get version of this app
     * @return string
     */
    public function getVersion()
    {
        $cache = $this->_cache;
        $numVersion = $cache->getItem('stats.num_version');
        if (!$numVersion->isHit()) {
            $version = !file_exists($this->_rootDir . '/RELEASE.TXT') ? 'dev' : file_get_contents($this->_rootDir . '/RELEASE.TXT');
            $numVersion->set($version);
            $cache->save($numVersion);
        }
        return $numVersion->get();
    }

    /**
     * 
     * Get name of this app
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return 'GH';
    }


}
```

Answer (score 3):

## 1. Why it happens

Symfony's `bin/console cache:clear` command clears the cache only from kernel cache dir, which is `var/cache/{env}` by default.

When you create instance of FilesystemCache, you can provide a path where you want to store your cache as a 3rd parameter. Here's a signature of FilesystemCache constructor

```
public function __construct(string $namespace = '', int $defaultLifetime = 0, string $directory = null)
```

If you don't provide 3rd parameter it will end up as `sys_get_temp_dir().'/symfony-cache'`, which is `/tmp/symfony-cache` on Linux.
As you can see it's a different directory and it won't be cleared by `cache:clear` command.

## 2. How to fix it

### The proper way

You need to create your own `data-cache:clear` command. It's very simple https://symfony.com/doc/current/console.html

In `execute()` method of your command you should instantiate your FilesystemCache and call `clear()` on it. Example:

```
protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
{
    $cache = new FilesystemCache();
    $cache->clear();
}
```

Then you can call `php bin/console data-cache:clear` from console.
If you decide to switch to some other caching engine in future (Redis, Memcached etc.) you can simply adjust that command to clear that cache.

### The wrong way

> It will only work if you keep using FilesystemCache and does not
>   provide fine-grained control of which cache you actually clear.

You can store your cache in `kernel.cache_dir` by passing a 3rd parameter to FilesystemCache when you instantiate it.
Example:

```
$cache = new FilesystemCache('', 0, $container->getParameter('kernel.cache_dir').'/data-cache');
```

or when configured as a service

```
Symfony\Component\Cache\Simple\FilesystemCache:
  arguments:
    - ''
    - 0
    - '%kernel.cache_dir%/data-cache'
```

This way Symfony's `cache:clear` command will work for you, but it's not a good idea to store these 2 types of cache in the same place.

> If you change some of your project files, you may want to clear only
>   kernel cache in `/var/cache` while keeping your data cache intact and
>   vice versa. That's why I recommend not to use this solution!

Comment: Thanks for the hint, it seems that when you don't provide a path, the cache is stored in the /tmp/ directory of the system. I was trying to clear that in production without success, so I had to provide a path and clear it from there, thanks a lot.